# I get [Errno 13] Permission denied error when trying to upload images

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, discord.py

```
await message.attachments[0].save('Images/' + '{0}'.format(message.attachments[0].filename))
            print('Downloaded {0}'.format(message.attachments[0].filename))
            path = 'C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Images/'
            os.chdir(path)
            files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getctime)
            images = (files)
            media_ids = [api.media_upload(i).media_id_string  for i in images]
            api.update_with_media(path, status='{0}'.format(message.content), media_ids=media_ids)
            print('{0.author.name} posted an (Image Attachment)'.format(message))
```

For some reason I can't seem to upload multiple images on Twitter because of this issue.

Fixed the issue because I forgot to include `files` but now it only uploads one image instead of all:

```
await message.attachments[0].save('Images/' + '{0}'.format(message.attachments[0].filename))
            print('Downloaded {0}'.format(message.attachments[0].filename))
            path = 'C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Images/'
            os.chdir(path)
            files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=os.path.getctime)
            images = (files)
            media_ids = [api.media_upload(i).media_id_string  for i in images]
            api.update_with_media(path + files[0], status='{0}'.format(message.content), media_ids=media_ids)
            print('{0.author.name} posted an (Image Attachment)'.format(message))
```

Comment: Could you please edit the full error you're seeing into the body of your question as text?

Comment: I fixed the issue because I forgot to include `files` next to the directory when uploading it to Twitter but now it only uploads one instead of multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Must be sure your Python IDE has been launched with Administration rights or make sure that the folder has the less possible permissions to let Python do whatever he wants to download some files or pictures into a protected folder, so you'll never have again a Permission error.

You got a permission error because you tried to write/copy/paste or download files into the C: path that's protected.

By default anything that's in the C: Path are protected even when you create your own folder by Python.

Hope that I was helpful for your question!

Comment: Im using aws lightsail and I get same error. I already change ownership of projects directory `sudo chown $USER /opt/bitnami/projects` but I still get this error. what permission should be granted ?